# SSL between WebCache server and Weblogic Server

Tags: ssl, https, weblogic, ssl-certificate

### Problem

I am running 2 servers, 1 for web cache (10.3) and one for weblogic (12c). I deployed an apex listener app on the weblogic server and created a site to server mapping in webcache which works great for non SSL connections. However when I enable SSL between client and webcache + webcache and weblogic, webcache cannot validate the certificate provided by the web logic server (I assume because it's a self signed certificate) and the connection drops.

If I enable SSL between the client and the web cache server and disable SSL between web cache and weblogic I get redirected to a non SSL URL and the page is not found.  In order for me to continue navigating through the website (APEX) I need to repeatedly add the `HTTPS://` prefix to the URL.

#### An example of the above scenerio:

1. `HTTPS://example.com/apex`
2. Result: page not found
3. URL becomes (in browser) `http://example.com/apex/f?=111111`

Adding `HTTPS://` to the front of the URL brings up the login page and I proceed to login.

### Rinse and repeat

This is somewhat complicated to explain, so feel free to ask questions. I have been stuck for several days.

Is there a way around the invalid certificate provided to web cache by web logic without getting a signed CA certificate (assuming this is my problem)? This is a development environment so it seems a bit much for testing.

Comment: Something that might help with self signed certs for testing is to run weblogic with `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true`

Comment: I debated doing that.  I was just concerned about that security risk that is involved with that method.  Ultimately, because I am essentially only using Web Cache as a reverse proxy it might not pose any real risk.  Thanks.